# Qt: Resizing QMenuBar corner widget

Tags: qt, resize, widget

I put a push button into the top-right corner of my main window menu bar:

```
QPushButton *pb = new QPushButton("Text");
pb->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Preferred, QSizePolicy::Preferred);

QMainWindow *mainWindow;
mainWindow->menuBar()->setCornerWidget(pb, Qt::TopRightCorner);
```

The initial layout is fine.  Sometime later, an asynchronous event changes the QPushButton's text to a longer string, but it gets clipped on the right.

I can see that the QPushButton's size changes when the string is updated.  The QPushButton is displayed correctly if the window is resized.  The problem appears to be getting the QMenuBar to recognize that the widget's size has changed.

This answer [How to auto change QPushButton width and QMenuBar corner widget width when change text of button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422439/how-to-auto-change-qpushbutton-width-and-qmenubar-corner-widget-width-when-chang) suggests resetting the corner widget.  I would rather avoid that, because my application's structure makes me jump through several ugly and awkward hoops to reset the corner widget after initializing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is simple. After updating the text of the button call     `menuBar()->adjustSize();` I have tested it in Qt5.5 and hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use QWidgetAction as a horizontal menu widget:

```
class TestMenu : public QWidgetAction
{
public:
    TestMenu(QObject *parent) :
        QWidgetAction (parent)
    {

    }
    virtual QWidget *createWidget(QWidget *parent)
    {
        QComboBox *combo = new QComboBox(parent);
        combo->setFixedWidth(300);
        return combo;
    }

    virtual void deleteWidget(QWidget *widget)
    {
        delete widget;
    }
};
```

...

```
QMenu *menu = new QMenu();
menu->addAction(new TestMenu(this));
menuBar()->setCornerWidget(menu);
```

[image: An example of how it looks]